# How do I access the value of the counter in a process?

Tags: erlang

In this program, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access the value of the counter in a process.

```
-module(counter).
-export([start/0,loop/1,increment/1,value/1,stop/1]).

%% First the interface functions.
start() ->
  spawn(counter, loop, [0]).

increment(Counter) ->
  Counter ! increment.

value(Counter) ->
  Counter ! {self(),value},
  receive
    {Counter,Value} ->
      Value
  end.

stop(Counter) ->
  Counter ! stop.

%% The counter loop.
loop(Val) ->
  receive
    increment ->
      loop(Val + 1);
    {From,value} ->
      From ! {self(),Val},
      loop(Val);
    stop -> % No recursive call here
      true;
    Other -> % All other messages
      loop(Val)
  end.
```

I assume it's:

```
{From,value} ->
      From ! {self(),Val},
      loop(Val);
```

which returns the value of the counter, but every time I use `PID ! {PID,value}`, or something similar to that it returns the thing after `!`, e.g. `{<0.57.0>, value}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

You shouldn't use `!` operator explicitly, it is considered an anti-pattern.  You could run into some problems with typos in atoms or some bad data, just like you did this time.

To ensure correct communication with you one usually create some wrapper functions witch handle correct data format and communication with process. Function just like `increment/1` `value/1` and `stop/1`. In fact if you would use those, you would get expected results; in your case, assuming that `PID` is your counter, just call `counter:value(PID).`

### Let me explain

There are few thing you seem to getting little bit wrong.

First of all `!` will send message to another process. And that's all it does.  Since everything in Erlang is expression (needs to return something, have a value) each call to `!` will return right hand side of `!`. `PID ! ok.` will return `ok`, no matter what (there is slight chance that it will fail, but lets no go there).  You send your message, and go on with your life, or execution.

Than, some process after receiving your message might decide to send you some message back. In case of `{From, value}` it will, in case of `increment` it wont. If you are expecting to get message back you need to wait for it and retrieve it from your mailbox. `receive` clause will do both waiting and retrieving.  So if you decise to use `!` on your own you should fallow it with `receive` with correct pattern match.  You can see that `value/1` function does just that.

Third thing is correct use of process ID's.  I guess you started your counter correctly and you have it's `Pid`, and you can send messages to it with `!`.  But if you expect it to send something back it needs to know your process ID, your address if you will.  So you should have called `PID ! {MyPid, values}`.  How to get `MyPid`? With `self()` function.  Again, just like in `value/1` function.

And last thing many people get wrong at the begging.  `counter` module is just a file with some functions, it's not whole actor/process, and it's not an object.  Fact that some `value/1` and `stop/1` are implemented in it, it doesn't mean that they will be run on counter actor/process.  They are functions like any other, and if you call them they will be evaluated in your actor/process, on your stack (same goes for calling them from shell, shell is just another actor).  You can `spawn` new process and tell it to run `loop/1` function, but that's all it does.  All `increment/1` `value/1` and `stop/1` calls will be executed "on your side".

If this is somewhat confusing try to imagine some simpler function inside counter module, like

```
add(A, B) -> 
  A + B.
```

You can execute it from shell even without any counter process started.  It will be created in your process, on your stack, it will add two numbers and return result.

This is important because when you call `counter:value(Counter).` it will execute `Counter ! {self(),value},` "on your side", on your process, so `self()` will return Pid of your process, not the Pid of counter.

In theory you don't need to know this if you are just using those wrapper function (API or interface if you will), but since you are learning Erlang I would guess you will soon have to write such wrapper. Understanding what happens where is crucial then.  Just remember that there is no magic in modules, no secret binding or special execution. Those are just plain old functions and they will be behaving just like in any other language.  Only `spawn`, `receive` and maybe `!` are little different.